# error using couchbase-spark-connector. throws BackPressureException

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, couchbase

I'm using AWS EMR with Spark 1.4.0 running as standalone cluster (not managed by Yarn or Mesos), and I'm using the [couchbase-spark-connector](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-spark-connector) version **1.0.0-beta** as of this writing, and the [couchbase-java-client](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-java-client) version **2.2.0-dp2** as of this writing.

I have a view written in Couchbase which returning me only the keys of my documents (about 300M+ keys).

I wrote a Spark program written in Scala 2.10.4 which for each key returned from the view I'm getting the document and want to save it all to AWS S3 filesystem.

My problem is that the Couchbase throws me an exception from type: **com.couchbase.client.core.BackpressureException** which says by [documentation](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-jvm-core-1.0.0/com/couchbase/client/core/BackpressureException.html):

> Identifies the need to back off on the supplier side when using a service, because the consumer is overloaded.

So my question is how can I fix this exception not to be thrown. I'd guess I would want to delay my requests but I can't see how to do that.

Attached below is my Spark code:

```
val couchbaseKeys = sparkContext.couchbaseView(ViewQuery.from(couchbaseDesignName, couchbaseViewName)).map(_.id).couchbaseGet[JsonDocument]()
    couchbaseKeys.map(Projection.projectCouchbaseObject(_)).filter(_ != null).saveAsTextFile(pathForExportedOutput)
```

And the Projection object with its method:

```
object Projection {

  val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)

  def projectCouchbaseObject(couchbaseObject: JsonDocument): String = {
    try {
      return couchbaseObject.id() + '\t' + couchbaseObject.content()
    }
    catch {
      case exception: Throwable => {
        logger.error("Failed project couchbase object. key was: " + couchbaseObject.id(), exception)
      }
    }

    return null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to tune the **maxRetries** and **maxDelay** config and that would solve your problem.

Take a look here : https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-spark-connector/blob/33e4b8382ae80e39ae0254489f5c410f10e7d549/src/main/scala/com/couchbase/spark/connection/CouchbaseConfig.scala#L30